# jQuery $.focus() not working with id and with input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, focus

I have a little problem:

I have a modal that opens after some result search with ajax: it opens and show all requested results correctly.

On close, I need to empty another div with ID "results", empty an input with ID "search" and focus on it:

- empty "results" is working
- changing value of "search" to "" is also working
- focus on "search" is not working

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <form action="" method="post" id="searchit">
      <div class="input-group mar-btm">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i> Ricerca:</span>
         <input type="text" id="search" tabindex="1" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Codice, EAN o Testo" />
       </div>
   </form>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4" id="results"></div>
```

**UPDATE:**
jQuery:

```
$(".modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
     $("#results").empty();
     $("#search").val('');
     $("#search").focus();
});
```

I also tried:

```
$(".modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
     $("#results").empty();
     $("#search").val('').focus();
});
```

and (is the only text input on this page):

```
$(".modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
     $("#results").empty();
     $("#search").val('');
     $('input[type="text"]').focus();
});
```

In every case, empty() and val() are working properly but nothing is working with focus()! No error thrown in console...

I can't figure out what I'm missing/doing wrong!

Some help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `$("#searc")[0].focus();`

Comment: `$("#searc").val('');` - Your field's `id` is `search`, not `searc`.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problems with this question that earn it a downvote; it's pretty clear.

Comment: Is the `#searc` typo in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: SORRY, the "searc" was a copying error. The problem is not a typo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems with trying to use `.focus()` in an event handler usually stem from the event being handled *also* having an affect on focus. To get around that, I usually just wrap the `.focus()` call in a timeout:

```
$(".modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
     $("#results").empty();
     $("#searc").val('');
     setTimeout(function() {
       $("#searc").focus();
     }, 10);
});
```

The timeout handler will run basically immediately after whatever triggered the event handler is all finished.

Comment: As Mr. Crowder noted, do make sure that the id value you're using matches the one in the HTML.

Comment: Definitely the right answer, now it's working properly! Nice way, thank you!